# How to setState in reducer - React

Tags: reactjs, state, store, reduce

I am learning to use Action, reducers and store.
Objective is to change the value of Msg(h1) to user.email when button is clicked.

CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-moon-x4kld?file=/src/index.js

How should i add setMsg()..in the reducer?

Below is the code:

**Index.js**

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/lib/integration/react";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage"; // defaults to localStorage for web
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import isLogged from "/src/isLogged.js";

import App from "./App";

const allReducers = combineReducers({
user: isLogged
});

const persistConfig = {
 key: "root",
 storage
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, allReducers);
const store = createStore(
persistedReducer,
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);
let persistor = persistStore(store);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
<StrictMode>
 <Provider store={store}>
  <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
    <App />
  </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
 </StrictMode>,
 rootElement
);
```

**App.js**

```
import "./styles.css";
import isLoggedUser from "/src/actions/user.js";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const [msg, setMsg] = useState("Start editing to see some magic happen!");
const user = {
id: 19,
login: "namrata",
firstname: "Namrata",
lastname: "B",
email: "Namrata@cranbourne.com.au"
};

const printValues = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

dispatch(isLoggedUser(user.email));
};
return (
 <div className="App">
  <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
  <h2>{msg}</h2>
  <button onClick={printValues}>Load User</button>
</div>
);
}
```

**actions/user.js**

```
const isLoggedUser = (data) => {

return {
  type:'isLogged', payload: data
}
}
export default isLoggedUser;
```

**isLogged.js**

```
 const initialState = {
 data: 0
};

const loggedUser = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case "isLogged":
  return { ...state, data: action.payload };
default:
  return state;
}
};

export default loggedUser;
```

Comment: What should the msg displays when you press the button?

Comment: its user.email as mentioned above..

Answer (score 0):

Okay! so the answer to my question was probably using Selector

I have added the following in App.js

```
const email = useSelector((state) => state?.user?.data || "abc");
```

and changed msg to email as follows

```
<h2>{email}</h2>
```